# Why has this VuePress Compilation failed?

Tags: frontend, blogs, vuepress

I'm trying to set up my personal blog. Everything's working fine under the dev environment, but when I when `vuepress build docs` it throws a huge bunch of errors. I'm not really familiar with frontend development, so I would really appreciate any help.
Repository: https://github.com/makabaka1880/makabaka1880/

```
> vuepress build docs                                                                                                                              [2:53] 130 ~/blog
wait Extracting site metadata...
tip Apply theme @vuepress/theme-default ...
tip Apply plugin container (i.e. "vuepress-plugin-container") ...
tip Apply plugin @vuepress/register-components (i.e. "@vuepress/plugin-register-components") ...
tip Apply plugin @vuepress/active-header-links (i.e. "@vuepress/plugin-active-header-links") ...
tip Apply plugin @vuepress/search (i.e. "@vuepress/plugin-search") ...
tip Apply plugin @vuepress/nprogress (i.e. "@vuepress/plugin-nprogress") ...
(node:18460) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)

✖ Client
  Compiled with some errors in 2.16s

✔ Server
  Compiled successfully in 1.91s

(undefined) assets/js/styles.8f3dca9f.js from Terser
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:80:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:139:10)
    at /Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:217:37
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at TerserPlugin.optimizeFn (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:160:259)
    at _next0 (eval at create (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:13:1)
    at eval (eval at create (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:30:1)
(undefined) assets/js/1.488cc455.js from Terser
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:80:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:139:10)
    at /Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:217:37
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at TerserPlugin.optimizeFn (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:160:259)
    at _next0 (eval at create (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:13:1)
    at eval (eval at create (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:30:1)
(undefined) assets/js/2.c4c6394e.js from Terser
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:80:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:139:10)
    at /Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:217:37
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at TerserPlugin.optimizeFn (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:160:259)
    at _next0 (eval at create (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:13:1)
    at eval (eval at create (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:30:1)
(undefined) assets/js/3.20d511cd.js from Terser
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:80:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:139:10)
    at /Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:217:37
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at TerserPlugin.optimizeFn (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:160:259)
    at _next0 (eval at create (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:13:1)
    at eval (eval at create (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:30:1)
(undefined) assets/js/4.05e21e52.js from Terser
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:80:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:139:10)
    at /Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:217:37
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at TerserPlugin.optimizeFn (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:160:259)
    at _next0 (eval at create (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:13:1)
    at eval (eval at create (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:30:1)
(undefined) assets/js/5.8aa2ead8.js from Terser
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:80:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:139:10)
    at /Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:217:37
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at TerserPlugin.optimizeFn (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:160:259)
    at _next0 (eval at create (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:13:1)
    at eval (eval at create (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:30:1)
(undefined) assets/js/6.64974a1b.js from Terser
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:80:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:139:10)
    at /Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:217:37
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at TerserPlugin.optimizeFn (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:160:259)
    at _next0 (eval at create (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:13:1)
    at eval (eval at create (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:30:1)
(undefined) assets/js/7.65f1a8c1.js from Terser
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:80:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:139:10)
    at /Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:217:37
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at TerserPlugin.optimizeFn (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:160:259)
    at _next0 (eval at create (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:13:1)
    at eval (eval at create (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:30:1)
(undefined) assets/js/app.3ed2f649.js from Terser
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:80:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:139:10)
    at /Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:217:37
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at TerserPlugin.optimizeFn (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:160:259)
    at _next0 (eval at create (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:13:1)
    at eval (eval at create (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:30:1)
(undefined) assets/js/vendors~docsearch.77260563.js from Terser
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:80:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:139:10)
    at /Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:217:37
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at TerserPlugin.optimizeFn (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:160:259)
    at _next0 (eval at create (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:13:1)
    at eval (eval at create (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:30:1)
(undefined) assets/js/10.fd115715.js from Terser
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:80:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:139:10)
    at /Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:217:37
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at TerserPlugin.optimizeFn (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:160:259)
    at _next0 (eval at create (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:13:1)
    at eval (eval at create (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:30:1)
(undefined) assets/js/11.dc75a80e.js from Terser
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:80:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:139:10)
    at /Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:217:37
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at TerserPlugin.optimizeFn (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:160:259)
    at _next0 (eval at create (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:13:1)
    at eval (eval at create (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:30:1)
(undefined) assets/js/12.9553ec31.js from Terser
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:80:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:139:10)
    at /Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:217:37
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at TerserPlugin.optimizeFn (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:160:259)
    at _next0 (eval at create (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:13:1)
    at eval (eval at create (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:30:1)
(undefined) assets/js/13.340176ac.js from Terser
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:80:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:139:10)
    at /Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:217:37
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at TerserPlugin.optimizeFn (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:160:259)
    at _next0 (eval at create (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:13:1)
    at eval (eval at create (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:30:1)
(undefined) assets/js/14.9cefb878.js from Terser
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:80:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:139:10)
    at /Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:217:37
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at TerserPlugin.optimizeFn (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:160:259)
    at _next0 (eval at create (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:13:1)
    at eval (eval at create (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:30:1)
(undefined) assets/js/15.ec4fc219.js from Terser
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:80:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:139:10)
    at /Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:217:37
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at TerserPlugin.optimizeFn (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:160:259)
    at _next0 (eval at create (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:13:1)
    at eval (eval at create (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:30:1)
(undefined) assets/js/16.f6c68e21.js from Terser
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:80:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:139:10)
    at /Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:217:37
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at TerserPlugin.optimizeFn (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:160:259)
    at _next0 (eval at create (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:13:1)
    at eval (eval at create (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:30:1)
(undefined) assets/js/17.9288c07f.js from Terser
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:80:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:139:10)
    at /Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:217:37
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at TerserPlugin.optimizeFn (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:160:259)
    at _next0 (eval at create (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:13:1)
    at eval (eval at create (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:30:1)
(undefined) assets/js/18.8b667d9a.js from Terser
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:80:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:139:10)
    at /Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:217:37
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at TerserPlugin.optimizeFn (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:160:259)
    at _next0 (eval at create (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:13:1)
    at eval (eval at create (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:30:1)
(undefined) assets/js/19.26ed2cff.js from Terser
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:80:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:139:10)
    at /Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:217:37
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at TerserPlugin.optimizeFn (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:160:259)
    at _next0 (eval at create (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:13:1)
    at eval (eval at create (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:30:1)
(undefined) assets/js/20.440b857a.js from Terser
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:80:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:139:10)
    at /Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:217:37
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at TerserPlugin.optimizeFn (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:160:259)
    at _next0 (eval at create (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:13:1)
    at eval (eval at create (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:30:1)
(undefined) assets/js/21.5bced47b.js from Terser
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:80:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:139:10)
    at /Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:217:37
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at TerserPlugin.optimizeFn (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:160:259)
    at _next0 (eval at create (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:13:1)
    at eval (eval at create (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:30:1)
(undefined) assets/js/22.c8592aa4.js from Terser
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:80:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:139:10)
    at /Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:217:37
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at TerserPlugin.optimizeFn (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:160:259)
    at _next0 (eval at create (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:13:1)
    at eval (eval at create (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:30:1)
(undefined) assets/js/23.acdc8b5e.js from Terser
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:80:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:139:10)
    at /Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:217:37
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at TerserPlugin.optimizeFn (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:160:259)
    at _next0 (eval at create (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:13:1)
    at eval (eval at create (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:30:1)
(undefined) assets/js/24.b04550e8.js from Terser
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:80:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:139:10)
    at /Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:217:37
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at TerserPlugin.optimizeFn (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:160:259)
    at _next0 (eval at create (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:13:1)
    at eval (eval at create (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:30:1)
(undefined) assets/js/25.8194eb9a.js from Terser
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:80:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:139:10)
    at /Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:217:37
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at TerserPlugin.optimizeFn (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:160:259)
    at _next0 (eval at create (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:13:1)
    at eval (eval at create (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:30:1)
(undefined) assets/js/26.60e5a607.js from Terser
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:80:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:139:10)
    at /Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:217:37
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at TerserPlugin.optimizeFn (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:160:259)
    at _next0 (eval at create (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:13:1)
    at eval (eval at create (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:30:1)
Error: Failed to compile with errors.
    at /Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/@vuepress/core/lib/node/build/index.js:190:16
    at finalCallback (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/webpack/lib/MultiCompiler.js:254:12)
    at /Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/webpack/lib/MultiCompiler.js:277:6
    at done (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:2931:13)
    at runCompilers (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/webpack/lib/MultiCompiler.js:181:48)
    at /Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/webpack/lib/MultiCompiler.js:188:7
    at /Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/webpack/lib/MultiCompiler.js:270:7
    at finalCallback (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:257:39)
    at /Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:273:13
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:33:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
    at onCompiled (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:271:21)
    at /Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:681:15
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
    at /Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:678:31
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:9:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
    at /Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1423:35
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:9:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
    at /Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1414:32
    at eval (eval at create (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:17:1)
    at /Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:321:9
    at TaskRunner.run (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/TaskRunner.js:48:7)
    at TerserPlugin.optimizeFn (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:227:18)
    at _next0 (eval at create (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:13:1)
    at eval (eval at create (/Users/makabaka1880/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:30:1)
```